# How to open "Turn system icons on or off" via command line?

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to get to the Windows 10 equivalent of this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUzkm.png) in order to show or hide the system clock.

The way I do it now, manually, is typing `turn syst` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle.

It seems like, since it appears in the Start menu, you should be able to open some sort of link to visit that specific screen.

Comment: I rejected the edit because I feel like the question reads better with the image inline. If the edit is proposed again, I'll let allow it, but I personally don't like that style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9} \SystemIcons
```

http://tenforums.com/tutorials/86339-list-commands-open-control-panel-items-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT of all things - a rollback war **on meta**, on **my own post** - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343685

Comment: Wow.... I've never done that and to me that seems rather extreme per the period length you're forced into the penalty box. Were they just asking you to affiliate something on your post or what? A back and forth rollback on Meta and BAM (out for ....) Daaaayuuuuum man!!

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I was referring to some software as "Steven’s ABC" and they wanted it as "My ABC" - pretty dumb reason really - and that account has 49,000 rep